# Cargar Spinner con base de datos SQLite Android

Tags: android-studio, base-de-datos, sqlite, spinner

Hola necesito ayuda para cargar un spinner desde una base de datos de la forma mas sencilla posible.

Tengo un clase en donde esto haciendo métodos de todo tipo lo ideal seria que desde la activity llame a esos métodos y cargue el spinner.

```
public ArrayList getAllClientes() {
    ArrayList list = new ArrayList<>();
    //String[] campos = new String[]{NOMBRE_CLIENTE, DIRECCION_CLIENTE};
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+TABLA_CLIENTE, null);

    try {
        while (c.moveToNext()){
        Cliente cli = new Cliente();
        cli.setId(c.getInt(0));
        cli.setNombre(c.getString(1));
        cli.setDireccion(c.getString(2));
        list.add(cli);
        }
    } finally {
        c.close();
    }
    return list;
}

public Cursor getAllClientes(){
    return db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+TABLA_CLIENTE, null);
}
```

Esos son los métodos que estaba intentado para traer los datos de la bd pero no se si me sirven y es así no se como setear el spinner

Comment: deberias pone el codigo que as intentado , este foro se trata de ayudarte con lo que tengas echo , no de que aparesca codigo de la nada

Comment: Agrega el código donde cargas el spinner.

Answer (score 1):

Primero crea tu spinner

```
<Spinner
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/GameSpinner"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

Luego usa

```
genreSpinnerAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
    dataSource.getAllGenres(),
    new String[]{DataBaseScript.GenreColumns.NAME_GENRE},
    new int[]{android.R.id.text1},
    SimpleCursorAdapter.FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER);
```

te dejo la referencia 
http://www.hermosaprogramacion.com/2014/10/android-spinners/